# Deep Learning architecture for input and output of different size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am quite new to deep learning and I am trying to play around with Tensorflow and Keras. I have worked through some of the tutorials that explain how to use CNN on labeled data.

Now I want to try something different. I have input data of size (m,n,o) and output data of size (m,n,p). Thus input and output data have the same number of pixels (m,n) but a different number of channels. Using the o parameters per pixel an output pixel with p channels should be generated.

How do I achieve that? Is a CNN a proper architecture or should I use a different architecture? Do you know any tutorials or buzz words regarding this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [Semantic Segmentation](http://blog.qure.ai/notes/semantic-segmentation-deep-learning-review). That sounds very similar. Usually the input has 3 channels (RGB) and the number of output channels equals the number of classes you want to detect.

There are quite a few CNN based architectures for this task, some of which are described in the link above, that could be maybe used for your task.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will take a look on it. Maybe on difference in my problem is that I don't have "classes" (i.e. integers) in the output channels but also float numbers. But maybe some of theses architectures fits my problem.

Comment: That should not be an issue. The class is usually always encoded as a one-hot-vector of float numbers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The applicable phrase in my part of the mind-space is "image-2-image".  Whether you want a CNN depends very much on what your translation involves.  If the transformation from `o` channels to `p` channels is independent of context, then CNN is *huge* overkill.

For instance, if you're trying to translate from display phosphors (RGB) to printer's separation (CYMK), then you need only a simple matrix multiplication on each individual pixel.

If, instead, you're involving spatial proximity and regional features to make the transformation -- using nearby pixels to recognize shapes, then generating the output image from those regional shapes -- then a CNN is warranted.